# How to encode attributeLables and value in JSON in yii 1?

Tags: php, json, yii, yii1.x

I have following code:

```
        $model = new JsonForms();
        $model->name = $this->name;
        $model->json = json_encode($this-> attributes);
```

And `$model->json = json_encode($this-> attributes);`encodes data in the following format:

```
{"t_name":"sdf","owner_name":"sdfgsdfg","telegram_number":null, "j_address":null}
```

Here t_name, owner_name etc. are variables. I need to save label names instead of variables (e.g `t_name` as First Name(first name is attributeLabels, or `owner_name` as Owner) ) in the format which displays below:

```
{"First Name":"sdf","Owner":"sdfgsdfg","Telegram Number":null, "Address":null}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Simply construct your own array of attributes:

```
$model = new JsonForms();
$json = [];

foreach ($model->attributes as $attribute => $value) {
    if ($attribute != 'json') {
        $json[$model->getAttributeLabel($attribute)] = $value;
    }
}

CJSON::encode($json);
```

Comment: It returns only array

Comment: @phpdev Who *it*? Do you assign `CJSON::encode` to something?